# How to add birthdate (tel type datefield class) to database and set an age restriction?

Tags: php, date

As the title suggests, I am having difficulty finding a clean and elegant approach to both adding a working php function for a user's birthdate and setting an age limit to my birthdate form that I have created:

```
<div id="date1" class="datefield">
            <input id="day" type="tel" maxlength="2" placeholder="DD"/> /
            <input id="month" type="tel" maxlength="2" placeholder="MM"/> /
            <input id="year" type="tel" maxlength="4" placeholder="YYYY" />
</div>
```

Here are the variables I have set up for the birthdate:

```
//initializing registration variables to prevent errors
$bday = ""; //birthday
$bday = date("Y-m-d");
```

In my database, the birth_date type is set as just a date. Is my setup correct so far? I understand that there may be a need to separate the date into month, day, and year, but all I am interested in is the valid year in which the user entered if I want to include conditions regarding the different number of days each month has.

Edit: With the paragraph that was just replaced, I realized that I am making this more complex than necessary. All I simply would like is for a php validation function that checks whether or not an inputted year is within the desired age specifications. So, on first code you see, I will be removing both day and month fields and only keep the year field.

Off tangent(but still relevant), should I not even bother to prompt users to inputting their DOB and instead have the required age limit documented in the terms/privacy policy(ies)? I know that even with a DOB form w/ restrictions not everyone will be willing to oblige to the rules ( ex. social net services like Facebook have 13 years as age limit but kids younger can work around that by lying; Twitter has their age limit documented rather than prompted).

Much advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Rethinking over my last body paragraph, I realized that I will be needing the birthdate year of users for a system I have planned so I guess in my case prompting a DOB would be necessary. However, since all I will ever be using is the year of the user's dob, its probably best and cleaner that I ditch asking for the month and day, right?

Comment: Check box [x] I attest that blahblah. Incorporate captcha

Comment: @DrewPierce So if I have a checkbox + captcha incorporated, most (if not all) of spams and bots will be prevented, right? I am kinda hesistant in using captcha though, because despite its necessity in preventing spammers and bots, it can be a frustrating experience for potential users trying to successfully register.

Comment: I struggle sometimes entering captcha ridiculous huh? I once read that a just as effective one is a graphic that even tells you the answer Like a joke. It reads What is 4+3? (Enter 7). It is random.

Comment: Who cares what they enter for a birthday. Just lies anyway

Comment: @DrewPierce This is a much cleaner alternative to captcha, though I wonder why many professional sites today that are prone to spam and bots do not make something like apparent? My registration form isn't big, so I don't know if I have the space to make the alternative visually appealing in terms of spacing. Is there a way where entries can be blocked if completed too quickly ( for instance, the system blocks users that fill out a form under an unrealistic amount of time )?

Comment: @DrewPierce True, but I need the year of users so that later I can use that year in a match-making process that takes the age of users into account when interacting with each other.

Comment: Many hundred variations on captcha with delays like stackoverflow's cheeseburger and salad one will robot delays. Though it is tough to distinguish their pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php has [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) function to check if date is valid. And to ensure the age you can use [date_add()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) function to create birthday datetime object + your range. Then you compare this object if it is less than current time.

Comment: That is really cool that checkdate is already a function. Okay then, so in approaching the age limit, I would simply just make a boolean/conditional statement, right?

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code to validate date

ValidationExpression="(((0|1)[1-9]|2[1-9]|3[0-1])/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/((19|20)\d\d))$"

Comment: Thank you, but may you please explain to me how this works? I am still learning php and web coding so I am very interested in learning about the code of others to better my coding intuition. Thanks.